# How disable state sharing in testng?

Tags: testng

I want to disable state share in testng tests. I want recreate private test fields every time when testmethod is invoked as in the JUnit framework. Is it possible? Or I need to run tests carefully with @BeforeMethods which reinitialized test class members for every method?

**P.S.** Also I wonder what is the purpose of @Before annotation in tesng? If I write some thing like this:

```
public class Test {
    TestedObject object;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp(){
        object = new TestedObject();

    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        object.setFieldA(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(object.calculate(), 10);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        object.setFieldB(1);
        Assert.assertEquals(object.calculate(), 10);
    }
}

public class TestedObject {
    //default values
    int a = 10;
    int b = 10;

    public void setFieldA (int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setFieldB (int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int caculate(){
        return a*b;
    }
}
```

I have to create some another method and run it manually every time to insure that new instance is created. Is there some other more compact way?

Answer (score 0):

Plese use `@BeforeMethod` instead `@BeforeTest` and that annotated method will be run before every test method, so you will get what you want.

Comment: Ok but how I can combine several Before methods? What if I want to add BeforeGroups method?

Comment: @Cherry You can use like this : `@BeforeGroups(groups = { "testMethodName1","testMethodName2" })` on your setUp() method. And you can have as many setup methods as you want annotated with @BeforeGroups with different methods selected.

Comment: Yes but I want to be insure that after I can test1 the state changes does not be affected when I call test2. So want the chain like: `@BeforeClass` - new Instance created, `@BeforeGroup` setted several properties, testMethod - test; next method all step the same. But when I start using `@BeforeMethod` to create new Instance all benefits from other `@Before` method are disappear, I must do all operation in one `@BeforeMethod` to insure independency. Is there a way to use several Before annotation and make tests independed?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bets will be `@BeforeClass` and `@BeforeMethod` to configure your test instances. Other @Before annotations are rather tricky to use right as they are not necessarily executed for each instance of your test class (`@BeforeTest, @BeforeGroup`)

```
public class Test {

  @BeforeClass
  public void runBeforeFirstTestDefinedInClass() {
    ...
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void runBeforeEachTestMethodExecution() {
    ...
  } 

  @Test
  public void testSomething() {
    ...
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void runAfterEachExecutedTestMethod() {
    ...
  }

}
```